# Shortening a class with __init__

Tags: python, class, methods, init

I created a Class that does math with Mixed numbers.

It takes two strings (f1 and f2) ex `'1+1/4'` and `'3+1/5'` and can add subtract multiply or divide them.

I was wondering if I could shorten the code using `__init__`
Can I just pass f1 and f2 to `__init__` and reduce the repetition?!

at the moment I have to put the following code into each method which takes in f1 and f2

```
coef1 = int(f1.split('+')[0])
coef2 = int(f2.split('+')[0])
num1 = int(f1.split('+')[1].split('/')[0])
num2 = int(f2.split('+')[1].split('/')[0])
de1 = int(f1.split('+')[1].split('/')[1])
de2 = int(f2.split('+')[1].split('/')[1])
```

Each method needs each of those variables to do math

Comment: When you attempted to put them into an init, what happened?

Comment: There is nothing here that looks like a class.  Please show more code.  One quick bit of advice is you can do multiple assignments from the split() function.  It would keep you from doing the same operation on the same data 3 times.  e.g. 
 `coef1,frac1=f1.split('+');  num1,de1=frac1.split('/')`

Answer (score 0):

You don't show any classes, where you could use `__init__`.
First you should write a function:

```
def parse_mixed_number(f):
    coef, numden = f.split('+')
    num, den = numden.split('/')
    return int(coef), int(num), int(den)

coef1, num1, den1 = parse_mixed_number(f1)
coef2, num2, den2 = parse_mixed_number(f2)
```

If you want to use classes, then, parse_mixed_number should be called in `__init__`:

```
from collections import namedtuple
class MixedNumber(namedtuple("MixedNumber", "coef,num,den")):
    def __new__(cls, f):
        coef, numden = f.split('+')
        num, den = numden.split('/')
        return tuple.__new__(cls, [int(coef), int(num), int(den)])
```